# Shouldn't we have a "differences" tag? Is there a point in that?

Tags: discussion, tags

There seems to be a lot of questions that deal with the differences, pros and cons of using one expression compared to another one. Should all this questions be filed under the "differences" tag, or is that the wrong approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd think that questions discussing when to use one fragment over the other easily falls under `grammar`. Or even `usage`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Most such questions have been using the [word-choices](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choices) tag. I know because most of my questions are of this sort so far.

Answer (score 0):

I ALMOST just created that tag prior to seeing this thread.  Yeah, I agree that word-choices is better.